# bzImage and grub config not installed to .dsk in yocto dsk build

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake

I am building yocto image with `bitbake`, with image type dsk (default had been `wic` which I changed to `dsk` in `local.conf`). It generates `bzImage, boot/grub/grub.conf`. But these are not installed in dsk.

As in .`dsk` format, I have two partitions holding identical EFI and the third partition as OS root file system.

In 1st two partitions tree are like,

```
├── EFI
│   └── BOOT
│       └── bootia32.efi
├── EFI_internal_storage
│   └── BOOT
│       └── bootia32.efi
├── emmc-partitions-data
└── rmc.db
```

So, there is no kernel and grub config here. How to install kernel and grub images to this partition as part of dsk image?

My another question is, what is the significance of having two identical partitions holding EFI?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no `dsk` image type in the current OpenEmbedded. What layers and versions are you using? Where is the `dsk`-image type defined?

Comment: This is local script added for dsk.

Answer (score 0):

- After exploring around, I ended up finding that vmlinuz has to be renamed form of bzImage and initrd renamed form of .cpio archive. Nothing much technical as such.
- We have to install grub config separately through installation script by putting in bbclass of bbappend (based on scope of use across the target) of image creating script. Seems like this is not generic requirement, not sure.

  `INST_LOC=${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/boot
  install -d ${INST_LOC}/boot/grub
  install -m 0644 ${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}/boot/grub/grub.conf
  ${INST_LOC}/boot/grub/grub.conf`